# Android Activity.Not.Found Intent

Tags: android, error-handling, android-activity

I have one Activity running and when I click a button I want the next Activity to pop up. It should be simple, but I don't know what's going on here.
I don't understand why I am getting this error. I have looked at other people's errors and tried to fix it, but nothings working. When I match the action name and when I call it in java I still get this error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is what I got for my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jordan.dictation"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Recorder" 
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <action android:name="com.jordan.dictation.RECORDER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is my Javacode for first activity that is suppose to call the other Activity "Recorder.java" when the button is clicked:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button bn_Add;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bn_Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_nav_add_recording);
    bn_Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO start other activity
            try
            {
                // this is the code that I am surrounding in the try/catch block
                Intent openRecorder = new Intent("com.jordan.dictation.RECORDER");
                startActivity(openRecorder);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // this is the line of code that sends a real error message to the log
                Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());

                // this is the line that prints out the location in
                // the code where the error occurred.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: is **Recorder.java** placed in a different package than **MainActivity.java**?

Comment: No, but good guess. I just needed an intent filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<activity android:name=".Recorder" 
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.jordan.dication.RECORDER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

you are not using intent filter in your mainfest file

Comment: Thank you soo much. What exactly does the intent-filter do? If you find something that explains it easy please share! Thanks again!

Comment: It basically lets the system know of a component's capabilities. For example, an Activity which can show web pages will declare it's intent filter as below:                                        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
 </intent-filter>

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. One more question, since it still relates to the issue which you've solved... When I made the fix (it works don't get me wrong) but why do I get the Warning {Exported activity does not require permission} at each activity that is not the MAIN activity? Thanks again!

Comment: This warning means that your activities are exposed to different-process apps that might instantiate them without any required permission.

for details see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#prmsn

Comment: I found the answer, thanks! android:exported="false" <--This code makes it so that no other applications have permission to this activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Recorder.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

instead of

```
Intent openRecorder = new Intent("com.jordan.dictation.RECORDER");
startActivity(openRecorder);
```

clean and built your code to make sure!

Comment: Is it more efficient or do you think that it just reads better?

Comment: Always works for me! Also its seems to me more complicated to start an Intent via Action (annoying the system to find it for you) instead of instantly open by class name! check out doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28%29